# Modify Simple Search in Hybris cockpit

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I'm trying to modify the simple search behaviour for the promotions. I want to search only on the 'name' field.
I did this:

```
<context type="PromotionSourceRule" component="simple-search">
    <yss:simple-search xmlns:yss="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/config/simplesearch">
        <yss:field name="name"/>
    </yss:simple-search>
</context>
```

but the problem is that the field 'name' is localized and my simple search now is searching only for the english language.

I have also german and dutch localization and I would to search also in these languages.

Any idea?

Comment: do you use Backoffice `Solr` Search or  `Flexible Search` ?

Comment: @Nomade how can I check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `simple-search` for localized fields.
You have to configure your language, see [`com.hybris.cockpitng.editor.localized.LocalizedSimpleEditor`](https://help.hybris.com/6.6.0/hcd/8c062ff286691014b2618f676f8099fe.html) and use [advanced-search widget](https://help.hybris.com/6.6.0/hcd/8b50ccf3866910149e1c9ebdd47f12be.html).

### LocalizedSimpleEditor

> Description
>
> A drop-down list version of the Localized Editor applied in the Advanced Search widget.
>
> Type
>
> Reference to any type which must be provided in the following format LocalizedSimple(  ), for example:
>
> LocalizedSimple(java.lang.String)
>      LocalizedSimple(java.lang.Integer)
>      LocalizedSimple(Reference(Product))

Example :

```
<as:field editor="com.hybris.cockpitng.editor.localized(com.hybris.cockpitng.editor.defaulttext)"  .../>
```

### Advanced search widget example

```
<context type="Product" component="advanced-search">
<as:advanced-search xmlns:as="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/config/advancedsearch" connection-operator="AND">
    <as:field-list disable-attributes-comparator="false" disable-subtypes-checkbox="false">
        <as:field name="code" operator="equals" selected="true"/>
        <as:field name="approvalStatus" operator="equals" selected="false"/>
        <as:field editor="com.hybris.cockpitng.editor.defaultlong" name="pk" operator="less" selected="true" sortable="false"/>
        <as:field name="modifiedtime" operator="greaterOrEquals" selected="true"/>
    </as:field-list>
<as:sort-field name="code" asc="false" />
</as:advanced-search>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't open that link, can you put here the part related to my question? Thank you very much

Comment: @sharkbait I've put more details in the answer.